# HTML-anchors and chrome

Tags: html

I'm working on a website where I'm using anchor points for linking to content on the same page - You all know that works :)

I have a really weird problem though.. The anchor works perfectly in Firefox

Site in firefox: http://nerdpatrol.dk/#home_services (click "Read more" on the first slide) - And you will see that the black area is placed perfectly below the menu

However, in Chrome the black box is placed underneath the menubar

Any idea as to what causing this.. I'm totally blank and feel like I've tried everything (the anchor even works in IE)

Oh..
I'm linking to a hidden div.. Nothing fancy.. It's simply contains the anchor

Answer (score 0):

The sourcecode of your website contains

```
<a href = "http://nerdpatrol.dk/#home_services_1">READ MORE</a>
```

But there is no element with the name `home_service_1` on the website.

It seems like IE and FF somehow fix this by pointing to the `home_service` element.

Fix it by changing the name accordingly.

Comment: That didn't do anything... the #home_services_1 was an attempt to place another hidder box to see if it corrected the issue... Which it didn't.. I have removed it now and checked the sourcecode for residual code, of which there is none.. Linking problem still persists though